# How do I track someone's IP address on facebook?

Tags: facebook, ip-address

There is this random dudette or dude on facebook that added my as a friend. He added random people too. He abuses and threats my friend. My friend told me so many times to show up to sort out the matter, but he never does.

How do we can find out who this impersonator is? 
We want to track this person's IP address.

Taimur

Comment: I'm almost positive that, Facebook terms of use aside, this is not going to be technically feasible.  Facebook has no doubt put extensive security in place to prevent this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Visual Basic to throw together a GUI to track his IP.

Comment: @user399680 can u please explain !

Comment: Before downvoting: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDD03yeLnU

Comment: user, you should have done this on your own account.  Free rep.